# Problema al mostrar datos de tablas relacionadas en Laravel8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Tengo la tabla productos y area_productos. un producto pertenece a un área y un área puede tener muchos productos. Cuando trato de acceder al método en la vista  no muestra nada, no se si estoy llamando mal al método o hay algo erróneo en los modelos.
En la vista debería mostrar un array con todos los datos del area, luego supongo que debería ser {{ $producto->areap->nombre}} para imprimir el nombre del area.
Adjunto los códigos:
Controller :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function productos(){
       
        $productos=Producto::all();
        return view('productos.productos',compact('productos'));

        
   }
}
```

Vista :

```
 @foreach ($productos as $producto)

 <div>
    <h3>{{ $producto->nombre }}</h3>
    <h5>{{ $producto->areap}}</h5>
 </div>

 @endforeach
```

Modelo productos :

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['area_producto_id','nombre','descripcion','foto'];

    //relacion uno a muchos Inversa 
    public function areap(){

        return $this->belongsTo(AreaProducto::class);

    } 
}
```

Modelo AreaProducto:

```
class AreaProducto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    // Debo especificar la tabla ya que en ingles laravel le pone la S para que sea plural, si em odelo es AreaProducto , 
    //laravel cree que la tabla es  Area_Productos (si con guion)
    protected $table = "areas_productos";
    protected $fillable=['nombre','foto'];
    

    // Relacion uno a muchos
    public function productos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class,'area_producto_id');
    }

    
}
```

y aca dejo las migraciones para complementar :

```
           Schema::create('areas_productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
                 $table->bigIncrements('id');
                 $table->string('nombre');
                 $table->string('foto');
                 $table->timestamps();
                });
           }
            Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('area_producto_id')->nullable();
                $table->string('nombre');
                $table->string('descripcion');
                $table->string('foto');
                $table->foreign('area_producto_id')->references('id')->on('areas_productos')->onDelete('set null');   
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Comment: Si la relación es uno a muchos entonces no se debe usar `belongsToMany` sino `hasMany`

Comment: Además muestranos por favor la consulta que tratas de llevar a cabo

Comment: Y precisamente sobre la línea de las relaciones de Eloquent y dado que mencionas un escenario de uno a muchos, entonces tampoco es correcto el `hasOne`

Comment: En tanta prueba he cambiado muchas relaciones para ver que me arroja. Pero ya lo deje con hasMany nuevamente. eso es en AreaProducto verdad? y en Producto como deberia dejarlo ?

Controller :
`
        $productos=Producto::all();
        return view('productos.productos',compact('productos'));

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal identificados y aplicados los métodos que define Eloquent para las relaciones entre entidades.

Los cuales según lo que expones deberían ser:

- `hasMany`
- `belongsTo`

Ahora *basándome* en la estructura que muestran tus tablas idenficamos que:

> Un área tiene muchos productos y un producto pertenece a un área

Dado lo anterior, entonces en el modelo `AreaProducto` deberías tener lo siguiente:

```
class AreaProducto extends Model
{
    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
    }
}
```

Por otro lado en tu modelo `Producto` deberías colocar lo siguiente:

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    public function areaProducto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AreaProducto::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora si la llave foránea que vincula a producto con áreas no siguiera las convenciones marcadas por Eloquent, entonces en el método `hasMany` debes pasar el nombre de la misma como segundo argumento quedando de esta forma:

```
$this->hasMany(Producto::class, 'area_producto_id');
```

Por cierto aunque no es directamente motivo de error, aún así te sugiero emplear la sintaxis de creación de [llaves foráneas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) que te permite Laravel en la versión que usas así:

```
$table->foreignId('llave_foranea')->constrained();
```

**Edición**

Ahora para el tema de la consulta, esto que haces: `Modelo::all()` no es que esté incorrecto pero solo te devolverá una colección de todos los registros de la entidad que tu marques, ahora por cada objeto de esa colección vendrá la llave foránea que te vincula con otra entidad pero hasta ahi y nadamás.

Lo que en este punto necesitas es por ejemplo [cargar de forma *ambiciosa*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) todos los productos y a su vez el área a la que pertenecen así:

```
$productosArea = Producto::with('areaProducto')->get();
```

Lo anterior te debería esta regresando:

- Una colección de todos los productos
- Por cada objeto de producto, dentro debería venir un objeto interno con los datos del área a la que pertenece

De tal suerte que puedas iterar y acceder a los valores de este modo:

```
@foreach($productosArea as $productoArea)
    {{ $productoArea->algunaPropiedad }}
    {{ $productoArea->areaProducto->algunaOtraPropiedad }}
@endforeach
```

**Lecturas de referencia**

- [Definición de la relación uno a muchos en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Ahí cambié las relaciones y de todas maneras le pasé el nombre de la llave foranea.  Ahora no arroja el error sql pero no me muestra nada. El controller lo tengo así <br/>
`
public function productos(){       
        $productos=Producto::all();
        return view('productos.productos',compact('productos'));       
   }
`
<br/>
Y en la vista pongo esto: @foreach ($productos as $producto) {{ $producto->areap}} @endforeach

Comment: Listo, me  ayudaste  a quedar claro con las relaciones de Eloquent  y con la sintaxis de las llaves foraneas cosa que no tenia idea que se hacia de esa manera, gracias !

Comment: Exacto , en el codigo que publiqué se que no accede al nombre pero es exacamento eso lo que necesito

Comment: Listo revisa la edición que hice @senku

Comment: Geniaaal ! muchas gracias, super bien explicado !hay cosas que no conocía ya que llevo poco tiempo con Laravel y esto me hizo entender muy bien. Gracias !!